# Empty Threads creating and killing after WCF service is hosted on Server

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf

I have created a WCF service and running it in my localhost. I opened MicroSoft "Process Monitor" to watch the background process. Surprisingly i saw lot of threads are creating and killing with zero UserTime and Kernal time.

I don't know why it is creating empty threads. Can anyone guide me why this much empty threads getting created and destroyed.

Snippet of Empty thread creating in Process Monitor:

[image]

Comment: Could be the `ThreadPool`

Comment: You wouldn't by chance be calling it every 8 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

A bundle of threads are created to handle the requests. This is called Thread Pooling. When the requests are high, more no of threads are created and added into the Thread Pool to handle the requests efficiently. These threads are reused after once they are created.

Thread Pooling reduces the amount of time to initialize the thread newly for every request.

Comment: Hi Venu, Thanks for your update. But i have a question. These empty threads are creating when no request is send to service. That means, no application/User is not using the service but the threads are created and destroyed. Will this thread creation affects the performance of service? If so, How can we reduce it?

Comment: @Mathew _"These empty threads are creating when no request is send to service. That means, no application/User is not using the service but the threads are created and destroyed. "_ - you should add that to your question

Comment: Hi Mathew, Based on the screenshot that you are showing, not all the thread are created for handling requests, Usually yes but not too many. I think there might be something fishy in the code.